# Connect to Ubuntu Server through SSH over the internet

Tags: ubuntu, windows, vpn, openvpn

I have a ubuntu server that I access locally through ssh, but I need to configure it to be able to access it through ssh from the internet. I connected eth1 to the internet and configured the interfaces file. I'm just lost trying to understand the concept of vpn and I followed several tutorials, but none of them worked. First I tried OpenVPN https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openvpn.html, I installed and configured it on Ubuntu and installed and configured OpenVPN client on windows, and I copied the config file and keys but when I try to connect I get connection timeout. This is the config file (client.ovpn) that I copied to my windows openvpn client:

```
##############################################
# Sample client-side OpenVPN 2.0 config file #
# for connecting to multi-client server.     #
#                                            #
# This configuration can be used by multiple #
# clients, however each client should have   #
# its own cert and key files.                #
#                                            #
# On Windows, you might want to rename this  #
# file so it has a .ovpn extension           #
##############################################

# Specify that we are a client and that we
# will be pulling certain config file directives
# from the server.
client

# Use the same setting as you are using on
# the server.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel
# if you have more than one.  On XP SP2,
# you may need to disable the firewall
# for the TAP adapter.
;dev-node MyTap

# Are we connecting to a TCP or
# UDP server?  Use the same setting as
# on the server.
;proto tcp
proto udp

# The hostname/IP and port of the server.
# You can have multiple remote entries
# to load balance between the servers.
remote my-server-1 1194
;remote my-server-2 1194

# Choose a random host from the remote
# list for load-balancing.  Otherwise
# try hosts in the order specified.
;remote-random

# Keep trying indefinitely to resolve the
# host name of the OpenVPN server.  Very useful
# on machines which are not permanently connected
# to the internet such as laptops.
resolv-retry infinite

# Most clients don't need to bind to
# a specific local port number.
nobind

# Downgrade privileges after initialization (non-Windows only)
;user nobody
;group nogroup

# Try to preserve some state across restarts.
persist-key
persist-tun

# If you are connecting through an
# HTTP proxy to reach the actual OpenVPN
# server, put the proxy server/IP and
# port number here.  See the man page
# if your proxy server requires
# authentication.
;http-proxy-retry # retry on connection failures
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port #]

# Wireless networks often produce a lot
# of duplicate packets.  Set this flag
# to silence duplicate packet warnings.
;mute-replay-warnings

# SSL/TLS parms.
# See the server config file for more
# description.  It's best to use
# a separate .crt/.key file pair
# for each client.  A single ca
# file can be used for all clients.
ca ca.crt
cert client1.crt
key client1.key

# Verify server certificate by checking
# that the certicate has the nsCertType
# field set to "server".  This is an
# important precaution to protect against
# a potential attack discussed here:
#  http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm
#
# To use this feature, you will need to generate
# your server certificates with the nsCertType
# field set to "server".  The build-key-server
# script in the easy-rsa folder will do this.
ns-cert-type server

# If a tls-auth key is used on the server
# then every client must also have the key.
;tls-auth ta.key 1

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# If the cipher option is used on the server
# then you must also specify it here.
;cipher x

# Enable compression on the VPN link.
# Don't enable this unless it is also
# enabled in the server config file.
comp-lzo

# Set log file verbosity.
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages
;mute 20
```

I don't know if I'm doing it right, and I'm not sure of the server address that I'm using to connect (10.8.0.1) which is the inet address of ifconfig tun0 on Ubuntu server.

I also tried this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VPN and I used the gateway of my router, but I didn't know what is the NT domain, and how to connect through ssh.

Comment: *VPN* has nothing to do with being able to *ssh* into a box, that's someting entirely different.

Comment: Ok, then could you please tell me how can I accomplish this?

Comment: You have to configure the router to let your server connect via certain ports to the outside internet.

Comment: You need to read about NAT, then configure your router accordingly, then find out your router's public IP address, which may change after every connect, then you can ssh to your router's ip address on the NATed port and it will pass this on to your ubuntu machine.